# Error during dependencies installation in pyspark 3.4.0 using a virtual environment and jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

#### Issue

I'm getting an error while installing the following dependency `spark-sql-kafka`. I'm using Jupyter notebook under a python virtual environment.

#### Project Configuration

Scala version: `2.12.17`
Pyspark version: `3.4.0`
Python version: `3.11`
Dependencies: `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.0`
oS: Unix (macOs)

#### Error displayed during compilation

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /Users/diegogallovalenzuela/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /Users/diegogallovalenzuela/.ivy2/jars
org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-b695ed4f-3ee2-4af4-bcdb-724f3ed5ce8f;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.3.2 in local-m2-cache
    found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.9.1 in local-m2-cache
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;2.0.6 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.4 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.4 in local-m2-cache
    found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 in local-m2-cache
    found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 in local-m2-cache
:: resolution report :: resolve 713ms :: artifacts dl 29ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.4 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.4 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.3.2 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;2.0.6 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.9.1 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   11  |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   11  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.3.2!kafka-clients.jar (2ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/diegogallovalenzuela/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/3.3.2/kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar

        [NOT FOUND  ] org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0!lz4-java.jar (1ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/diegogallovalenzuela/.m2/repository/org/lz4/lz4-java/1.8.0/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar

        [NOT FOUND  ] org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.9.1!snappy-java.jar(bundle) (0ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/diegogallovalenzuela/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.9.1/snappy-java-1.1.9.1.jar

        [NOT FOUND  ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;2.0.6!slf4j-api.jar (0ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/diegogallovalenzuela/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.6/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.3.2!kafka-clients.jar

        :: org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0!lz4-java.jar

        :: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.9.1!snappy-java.jar(bundle)

        :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;2.0.6!slf4j-api.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [download failed: org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.3.2!kafka-clients.jar, download failed: org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0!lz4-java.jar, download failed: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.9.1!snappy-java.jar(bundle), download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;2.0.6!slf4j-api.jar]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1528)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

#### Project Code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
import os

scala_version = '2.12'  # TODO: Ensure this is correct
spark_version = '3.4.0'
packages = [
    f'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_version}:{spark_version}',
    'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.3.2'
]
spark = SparkSession.builder\
   .master("local")\
   .appName("kafka-example")\
   .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(packages))\
   .getOrCreate()
spark

# Define the Kafka broker(s) and topic(s)
kafka_brokers = "localhost:9093"
kafka_topic = "topic1"

# Define the Kafka source options
kafka_options = {
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": kafka_brokers,
    "subscribe": kafka_topic,
    "startingOffsets": "latest"
}

# Read from Kafka as a streaming DataFrame
streaming_df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_brokers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
    .load()

# Define the schema for the value column
value_schema = spark.read.json(streaming_df.select("value").limit(1).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).schema

# Parse the value column as JSON and select required fields
parsed_df = streaming_df \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), value_schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.column1", "data.column2", "data.column3")

# Define the sink for the parsed data (e.g., console, file, etc.)
sink_query = parsed_df \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

# Start the streaming query
sink_query.awaitTermination()
```

#### Resources and similar question consulted

1. [github](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb)
2. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73665015/data-source-kafka-fails-with-pyspark)

#### Update

I'm not sure if this is a `PATH` or network connection error, but it works if I run it on Windows. Need to make it work on Unix (macOs).
If I don't add the dependencies the app runs, but when I try to initialize spark streaming using Kafka client I got the error: `AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide.`, which makes sense.

Comment: in the [kafka sql example](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb) provided, the variable `packages` has two elements. One is the `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` dependency, and the other one is `kafka-clients` that wasn't added in your code. You are getting an error message saying that the dependency `kafka-clients` wasn't found. Not sure if that could be the root cause

Comment: I deleted that line of code before posting, but with or without it, I'm still getting the same error. Not sure if this is about defining ```PATH```variables in virtual environment?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. could you find the solution? @DiegoGallo